# Откуда взялось слово "катала"?

Tags: жаргонизмы

Объясните, пожалуйста, происхождение слова "катала", в значении "карточный шулер"? В продолжение вопроса о поговорке: "Не мытьём, так катаньем".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В специальном словаре указывается, что катала - это обманщик, жулик; шулер. Также приводятся примеры: "Сегодня у него был катран. Для крупной игры собрались трое известных "катал". "Он - шестерка. Катала, мелкий игрочишка в карты и на бегах".

Перевод на английский: sharp, grifter,  mechanic, broadsman.

Answer (score 1):

Я уже несколько раз тут писал по разным поводам, что достоверной этимологии "фени" (воровского жаргона) обычно не существует, не буду останавливаться на причинах этого и подробностях, просто примите к сведению, что любое "авторитетное"  или "научное" мнение в этих случая - не более чем субъективная версия.

Это вполне касается и слова "катала".
Но первое, что приходит на ум, - общеупотребительное "катать", "прокатить" - обманывать, разочаровывать, и проч.

Сравните - прокатить (на вороных). Вороные - это понятно, черные шары при голосовании, но прокатить-то почему? Только от переносного значения катать - "обманывать" (в данном случае возможно даже "обманывать ожидания").

Насколько все это верно, как уже сказал, утверждать нельзя.
Но других ненадуманных (и при этом что-то объясняющих, а не просто постулирующих!!!) версий я не знаю.

Comment: Благодаря вашему ответу я вспомнил, что в воровской среде нередко употребляется слово "закатать" в значении "украсть".

Comment: Ну да...
Похоже, что это одного ряда слова.
Я мимо полки пойду - в словарь гряну, как там "катать" и "катала" согласуется. Сейчас уж больно подниматься не охота)))

Answer (score 0):

От каталы, жулика. Три наперстка и шарик. Мастерства минимум. Эффект потрясающий. Карты более интеллектуально, для более образованных специальные игры и мастерство гораздо выше. А три листика - для тех же лохов.

Comment: Это маловероятно, т.к. у подобных деятелей есть своё называние - напёрсточники и колпачники, особого мастерства там не требуется:"Кручу-верчу, обмануть хочу! Смотрим внимательно, - выигрываем обязательно!" Катала же - это профессионал, не просто карточный игрок, а мошенник высокого класса.

Comment: Напесрточники - тоже профессионалы...
Но проблема в том, что совершенно не понятно, что карточный шулер, появившийся еще в позппозапрошлом веке мог получить имя от современных наперсточников (которых ко всему прочему обычно и не называют каталами).